# Redux toolkit + Typescript: extraReducers

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to add typescript to my react/redux project.
Here is my slice:

```
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk, AnyAction, CaseReducer, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
export interface RequestStateBase {
    failed: boolean;
    executing: boolean;
    initialLoad: boolean;
    message: string | null;
    errors: any[]
}
const handlePending = (state: RequestStateBase) => {
    state.failed = false;
    state.executing = true;
    state.message = '';
}

const createCharacter = createAsyncThunk(
    'character/new',
    async (model: any) => characterClient.createCharacter(model)
);

const characterSlice = createSlice({
    name: "character",
    initialState: initialState,
    reducers: {
        cleanCharacterData: (state: CharacterState) => {
            //...
        },
        //...
    },
    extraReducers: builder => {
        builder.addCase(createCharacter.pending, handlePending),
        //...
    }
});
```

In VS Code everything is fine, but I'm getting the following error during the build:

```
Line 78:9:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions
```

the line 78 refers to `builder.addCase(createCharacter.pending, handlePending)`

How to fix that?

Comment: please provide reproducable example. I mean with all imports

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `,` after that line - you probably wanted to write `;`.

The comma operator will not do any real harm there, but generally can cause unexpected behaviour - and it really seems to irritate JSHint there.

Answer (score 5):

For anyone googling that ends up here, I needed to add a type annotation to the `builder` parameter in order to get type inference for the slice's state. Without it, as soon as I added `extraReducers` the slice had an inferred type of `any`.

For example, within my `const authSlice = createSlice({ ... })`, the `extraReducers` field is now typed as:
`extraReducers: (builder: ActionReducerMapBuilder<AuthState>) => { ... }`

Comment: Thanks so much; I'd been searching for this for hours.